# How to make button to post data with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, button, submit, send

Using Google and this site, I've made a simple form to send data with jQuery.

**My HTML code:**

```
<a href="javascript:AddPoke('{news-id}', 'poke')">ADD</a>
<div class="area"></div>
```

**And jQuery:**

```
function AddPoke(id, action){
 var response = $('#dle-poke').val()
  $.post(dle_root + 'engine/ajax/poke.php', {id: id, text: response, action: action},
   function(data){
    if (data == 'ok') {DLEalert(dle_p_send_ok, dle_info);}
    else {DLEalert(data, dle_info);}
});

$('.area').append("<div id='dlepopup'><textarea name='dle-poke' id='dle-poke'></textarea></div>");
$("#dlepopup").slideDown(700);
};
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make a send or submit button to post this data! I am very inexperienced with jQuery and I would appreciate any help!

Comment: question is not clear.... which data u want to send and where do u want the submit button ??

Comment: write some text in textarea and send to engine/ajax/poke.php

Comment: r u gettin anything in reponse..console.log(response)  or alert (reponse) and see...

Comment: no i did not get any error and something in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML CODE:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:submit_value();" >Add </a>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script>
    function submit_value()
    {
       alert($('#first_name').val());
       alert($('#last_name').val());
    }
</script>
```

When you have enter any text in textfields then click on ADD link to display the alert message here display the text as you have write in textfileds.

Note: Please include the latest jQuery file in head tag.

Comment: thanks my dear friend, i fixed with this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721701/easy-way-to-post-form-values-using-jquery